# recursive sql to create tree structure from pair/relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

Our helpdesk software have a table in MS-SQL 2008 to keep track of relationship between items in the network.

I am trying to create a report, a treeview, that can show which items in our network, a certain item is needed for, on multiple levels.

The table has theese fields:

```
| pair_id | item_id   | rel_type_id  | 
|---------|-----------|--------------|
|    1    |    1      |      27      |
|    1    |    3      |      28      | 
|    2    |    1      |      27      |
|    2    |    2      |      28      | 
|    3    |    2      |      27      |
|    3    |    4      |      28      | 
|    4    |    2      |      27      |
|    4    |    5      |      28      |
```

where rel_type_id is:

```
 28 = depends on 
 27 = needed by
```

i.e. Server01 is needed for App01, which is needed for App01_web and ends up in something like this:

```
 1 (Server01)
  +--2 (App01)
     +--4 (App01_web)
     +--5 (App01_console)
  +--3 (db01)
```

and so on...

is there a way to parse down recursively (i.e. CTE) to find all items 
depending on i.e. item 1 (Server01) in this table?

The wanted output is a table looking something like this:

```
| parent_id | item_id | item_name     | level |
|-----------|---------|---------------|-------|
|     1     |    2    |    App01      |   0   | 
|     1     |    3    |    db01       |   0   |
|     2     |    4    | App01_web     |   1   |
|     2     |    5    | App01_console |   1   |
```

I have tried a couple of the CTE examples here, but I cant get them to work properly with this table. I suspect it is because I have no parent/child relationships in the table except for the rel_type_id value. Unfortunately, I cannot change the table.

Comment: So based on your input data, what do you want the output to look like? Plus could you share what you tried so far?

Comment: Added wanted output to question text.